# Angular 2 how to fire javascript inside of an app component

Tags: angular

I'm trying to fire a JS code inside of app.component.ts, but it's not working for some reason.

```
export class AppComponent {
  alert("test");
}
```

Can you please tell me why isn't it firing "test" alert?

Comment: Add it to your constructor or ngOnInit... `ngOnInit(){alert("test")}`

Comment: you need to call the ``alert()`` inside a function . Call ``alert()`` inside the ``constructor()``

Comment: What does the compiler say?

Comment: @torazaburo can you please tell me how do I check it?

Comment: I believe this is a beginner question, nevertheless I tried to answer your question below. I hope it will help on your journey to become a good developer.

Comment: Yeah, omt66, np... I'll select your question. But frankly AJT_82 and CruelEngine just said that 15mins before your answer.

Comment: You should be running `ng build` or `ng serve` or the equivalent to run your program. Look at the output. Or type your code into the TS playground at http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

```
export class AppComponent {
    constructor() {
        alert("test");
    }    
}
```

Or if you want to do something after the component initialization then implement the code below:

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
    constructor() {
       // construct your object here    
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        alert("test");
    }
}
```